# Where find Kate text editor key map / shortcuts config file?

Tags: migration, config, keyboard-shortcuts, restore, kate

Where do I find the config file that contains Kate text editor's keyboard shortcuts, so that I might copy it to a new installation?

And how might I otherwise restore the key settings conveniently?

I'm trying to recover Kate config, while migrating from broken linux installation.

I copied most those Kate config files I found. This has restored to Kate my theme, snippets and sessions. But all the keyboard shortcuts I set up (using its very well made keyboard shortcut dialog) are not restored. Indeed, my recovered snippets are not much use because the key bindings are no longer there. They must be there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just picking the editor up and was wondering where you configure them

I think you go to settings, shortcuts, and then export them and then import to the other machine

I *think*

Documentation seems a bit sparse about shortcuts

Comment: As of October, 2023, I tried this and it doesn't include keyboard shortcuts I use a lot. I went back to the older computer that I'm migrating from and I can't even find, under Keyboard Shortcuts, a lot of shortcuts to functions like Find Next and others. Exporting exports something, but not a lot of the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Searched this myself today and document it for there future now. You find the keymapping in this file:

```
/home/<USERNAME>/.local/share/kxmlgui5/katepart/katepart5ui.rc
```

Using Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon.